# Adding elements in Non-synchronized ArrayList using java parallel stream

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, parallel-processing, java-stream

I want to run this code in parallel using java parallel stream and update result in two `ArrayList`. The code given below is working fine except that the non-thread-safety of ArrayList may cause incorrect results, and I don't want to synchronize the `ArrayList`. Can someone please suggest me a proper way of using parallel stream for my case.

```
        List<Integer> passedList= new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> failedList= new ArrayList<>();

        Integer[] input = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(input);

        myList.parallelStream().forEach(element -> {

            if (isSuccess(element)) {//Some SOAP API call.
                passedList.add(element);
            } else {
                failedList.add(element);
            }

        });
        System.out.println(passedList);
        System.out.println(failedList);
```

Comment: a CompletableFuture might be more appropriate here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An appropriate solution would be to use [`Collectors.partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
Integer[] input = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(input);

Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> map = myList.parallelStream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(element -> isSuccess(element)));

List<Integer> passedList = map.get(true);
List<Integer> failedList = map.get(false);
```

This way you will have no thread-safety problems as the task will be decomposed in map-reduce manner: the parts of the input will be processed independently and joined after that. If your `isSuccess` method is slow you will likely to have performance boost here.

By the way you can create a parallel stream from the original array using `Arrays.stream(input).parallel()` without necessity to create an intermediate `myList`.